# rails : polymorphism / abstract / inheritance : case study

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I'm trying to migrate my project from php to rails. Mow, I'm faced with a pb to witch I had solution with php, but I can't figure out how to make it work with rails.

Here are my tables

```
ads
  id
  category_id
  title
  text

ad_real_estate_details
  id
  ad_id
  nb_room
  floor

ad_car_details
  id
  ad_id
  color
  brand
```

Here is what I succeed to do:

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id :title, :text, :ad_real_estate_details
  has_one :ad_real_estate_details
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ad_real_estate_details, allow_destroy: true
end

class AdRealEstateDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ad
  validates :ad_id, presence: true
end
```

However, this will not work for other category than real_estate.

So I was thinking of polymorphism, but polymorphism means I should add a reference in my "ad" table to the detail tables, and remove annonce_id from detail tables , what I think is nonsense as some ads can have no detail, and details are non-sense without an ad.

I was also thinking of a abstract class AdDetails, and  AdRealEstateDetail would inherite from it, but this is not possible with rails as all subclasses will share the same table.

Does anyone have a solution for this kind of problem?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that you want to store different "details" depending on the ad type?

One simple solution would be to serialize the "details" as JSON (or whatever format you like), and store them in a TEXT column.

Comment: I cant do this as I have a multicriteria search form for searching ads according to details.

Comment: That doesn't in any way stop you from storing the details as JSON in a single database column which is used for all ad types.